# Class templating to process pcl::PointCloud objects with different point types

Tags: c++, templates, point-cloud-library, point-clouds

I am trying to use template classes to use my functions regardless of the point type. I read the “Writing a new PCL class” tutorial but I have not got it. I will share the simplest class where I am trying to use this technique.  Its only function is to create the KDtree of a pointcloud in the correct point of the execution of a parent tree of processes.

KdtreeBuilder_Process.h

```
#ifndef KDTREEBUILDER_PROCESS_H 
#define KDTREEBUILDER_PROCESS_H 
#include "ProcessManager/ProcessConcurrent.h" //Parent class 
#include <pcl/kdtree/kdtree_flann.h>

class KdtreeBuilder_Process:public ProcessConcurrent 
{ 
public: 
    KdtreeBuilder_Process(pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZ>::Ptr inputCloud,pcl::KdTree<pcl::PointXYZ>::Ptr cloudKdtree); 
    virtual void run(); //method that executed when the process starts 
private: 

    pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZ>::Ptr mInputCloud; 
    pcl::KdTree<pcl::PointXYZ>::Ptr mCloudKdtree; 
}; 

#endif // KDTREEBUILDER_PROCESS_H
```

KdtreeBuilder_Process.cpp

```
#include "KdtreeBuilder_Process.h" 

KdtreeBuilder_Process::KdtreeBuilder_Process(pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZ>::Ptr inputCloud,pcl::KdTree<pcl::PointXYZ>::Ptr cloudKdtree): 
    mInputCloud(inputCloud),mCloudKdtree(cloudKdtree) 
{ 

} 

void KdtreeBuilder_Process::run(){ 
    mCloudKdtree->setInputCloud(mInputCloud); 
}
```

My intention is to be able to use this class with any point type that contains XYZ coordinates

Thanks for your support. 
BR

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solve the issue. Here is the final solution using only header file:

KdtreeBuilder_Process.h

```
#ifndef KDTREEBUILDER_PROCESS_H
#define KDTREEBUILDER_PROCESS_H
#include "ProcessManager/ProcessConcurrent.h"
#include "PointDefinitions.h"
#include <pcl/kdtree/kdtree_flann.h>
#include <QDebug>

template<class PointType>
class KdtreeBuilder_Process:public ProcessConcurrent
{
    typedef typename pcl::PointCloud<PointType>::Ptr PointCloudPtr;
    typedef typename pcl::KdTree<PointType>::Ptr KdTreePtr;

public:

    KdtreeBuilder_Process(PointCloudPtr inputCloud,KdTreePtr cloudKdtree): mInputCloud(inputCloud), mCloudKdtree(cloudKdtree) { }
        virtual void run(){
            mCloudKdtree->setInputCloud(mInputCloud);
        }
    private:

        PointCloudPtr mInputCloud;
        KdTreePtr mCloudKdtree;
};

#endif // KDTREEBUILDER_PROCESS_H
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all when dealing with templates you have to accept that all implementation will need to be moved to header files. If you want `KdtreeBuilder_Process` to be a template that takes class of point in parameter you just need to add appropriate template declaration syntax:

```
template<class PointType>
class KdtreeBuilder_Process:public ProcessConcurrent 
{ 
public:
```

If `PointCloud` class is ready to accept all classes with XYZ coordinates you just need to change your code accordingly

```
    KdtreeBuilder_Process(pcl::PointCloud<PointType>::Ptr inputCloud,pcl::KdTree<PointType>::Ptr cloudKdtree): mInputCloud(inputCloud), mCloudKdtree(cloudKdtree) { } 
    virtual void run(){ 
        mCloudKdtree->setInputCloud(mInputCloud); 
    } 
private: 

    pcl::PointCloud<PointType>::Ptr mInputCloud; 
    pcl::KdTree<PointType>::Ptr mCloudKdtree; 
};
```

Good luck!

Comment: Thanks for your answer @W.F. Looks simple but I have problems with the constructor parameters. Is not possible to include boost shared pointers in the constructor of a templated class?  I have the error "C2061: syntax error: identifier 'Ptr'"